# Powershell Need to copy from remote machines onto my machine

Tags: powershell, copy, copy-paste, paste

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\MSGLOG\COPY.txt"

ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        Copy-Item "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DST\\messaging*.log" -Destination "MYMACHINE\temp\MSGLOG\$Computer\"
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do its copy logs from ~400computers onto my machine. Each computer is using a date naming format for these logs so I want to copy these file into a folder named after what computer they came from but after many many attempts I cannot figure this out.

Comment: `Invoke-Command` takes a `[string[]]` arg for `ComputerName` so you can actually simplify your code to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content 'C:\temp\msglog\copy.txt') -ScriptBlock { ...`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a need to `Invoke-Command` in this situation. You should be able to copy from the `\\hostname\C$\.`

Ex (Untested):

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\MSGLOG\COPY.txt"
$MyMachine = "myMachine"

foreach($Computer in $Computers)
{
    Copy-Item -Path "\\$Computer\C$\Program Files (x86)\DST\" -Include "messaging*.log" -Destination "\\$MyMachine\temp\MSGLOG\$Computer\" -Verbose -WhatIf
}
```

If that gives you the results you are looking for, just remove `-whatif` and run again.

Note: Your example shows the destination to be a share. From the name of `MyMachine` I would assume this is local. If so, change the `-Destination` to a local path (just to avoid unnecessary slowdown) . Also, included `-verbose` in order to print what it is doing during the `Copy-Item` process

Comment: You don't need to escape the `$` since it's not followed by a valid variable-naming-character.

Comment: Just as a reference, `C$` is a SMB share.  The only restriction I can imagine is if the SMB port is blocked by a firewall

Comment: "*I don't see a need to Invoke-Command in this situation*" - 400 computers copying their logs in parallel, vs copying them serially one after another.

Answer (score 1):

`$computer` is defined on your local computer, but the scriptblock runs on the remote computer. When the remote computer tries to use `$computer` it gets an empty string.

You either need the `$using:computer` form which will bring the value into the scriptblock and over to the remote computer:

```
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\TEMP\MSGLOG\COPY.txt"

ForEach ($computer in $computers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        Copy-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\DST\messaging*.log" -Destination "\\MYMACHINE\temp\MSGLOG\$using:Computer\"
    }
}
```

or you need a variable which the remote computer has already, like `$env:COMPUTERNAME`.

Comment: Alternatively just pass `$Computers` to `-ComputerName` and use `$Env:ComputerName` in the copy command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell 5.1 on your host and your remotes you can use `Copy-Item` with its `FromSession` or `ToSession` parameters. Example from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server01" -Credential "Contoso\PattiFul"
Copy-Item "C:\MyRemoteData\test.log" -Destination "D:\MyLocalData\" -FromSession $Session
```